# mongodb deletes product before specified time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i'm using mongodb to auto delete product when i set a specified time ,i gave it 3600 seconds which is an hour but it keeps deleting under 2minutes

this is my database

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const DealSchema = new Schema(
  {
    category: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Category" },
    owner: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Owner" },
    title: String,
    description: String,
    photo: String,
    price: Number,
    stockQuantity: Number,
    reviews: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Review" }],

    createdAt: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now,
      expires: 3600
    }
  },
  {
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
    toJSON: { virtuals: true }
  },
  {
    timestamps: true
  }
);
const Deal = mongoose.model("Deal", DealSchema);
module.exports = Deal;
```

it deletes under 2 minutes, please how can i go about this

Comment: can you show the "insert" code?

Comment: @TomSlabbaert this my complete mongodb code

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/expire-data/#expire-documents-after-a-specified-number-of-seconds) you need to have an index defined for the field to make it work. I'm not sure when you set `expired` whether mongoose sets index automatically or not but you can try explicitly setting index as shown below

```js
DealSchema.index({createdAt: 1}, {expireAfterSeconds: 3600});
```

Comment: OP claims that documents are disappearing too quickly, this means the index is created, which means the issue is not related to index creation.

Comment: Well, then it could be setting a date thing, maybe `new Date()` will do the trick instead of `Date.now()`